# Android: TextView not updating after initial update

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview, realm

Bear with me - new to Android dev. My TextView only updates on the first entry. Subsequent updates to that entry (with the same PrimaryKey) do not update in the TextView.

I have tried a couple of things - notifyDataSetChanged(), invalidate(), adding a Handler to my Activity, but it's giving me errors.

Here is the Adapter code:

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RealmViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(FrameLayout container){
        super(container);
        tvEntryDate = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tv_entry_date);
        tvAvgDayPain = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tv_avg_pain);
    }
}

public EntryAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Entry> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate, boolean animateResults) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate, animateResults);
}

public ViewHolder onCreateRealmViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((FrameLayout) v);
    return vh;
}

public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final Entry entry = realmResults.get(position);
    tvEntryDate.setText(entry.getEntryDate());
    tvAvgDayPain.setText(""+entry.getAveragePain());
```

After debugging, I'm seeing that the realm is committing the update transaction, but the onBindRealmViewHolder only fires once when the app is started - not sure if this is the culprit.

Comment: what's realmResults in onBindViewHolder() ?

Comment: @PhanDinhThai RealmResults<Entry> realmResults. In my Activity, i have... RealmResults<Entry> entries = realm.where(Entry.class).findAllSorted("entryDate");
        final EntryAdapter entryAdapter = new EntryAdapter(this, entries, true, true);

Comment: it's your problem. You should re-init value of realmResults and then call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: You can also see an example of a RyclerView using Realm here: https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/ui/recyclerview, perhaps that can give you some ideas what is wrong in your code.